# I Need help unrooting my device

Tags: htc-desire, rom, stock-android, unrooting, att

Device: HTC Inspire 4g.

My Device was having some hardware issues, so i complained to AT&T and offered to send me a new device.  I have to now return my old device but it is ROOTED.  I do not want to send it back in this condition because I fear I will get caught and have to pay full price for the device.

My question is how should I go about unrooting this device.  I've seen many different forums and topics, but most of these methods are not working for me.

Install stock AT&T Rom - Could not find the zip file anywhere on the internet.
I've tried using an [RRU](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=952224) but my device cannot be detected by my PC.

If anybody can help me get either of these 2 methods to work, or come up with a new method it would be greatly appreciated.

Thank You

Comment: For the ROM, you might want to check [Where can I find stock or custom ROMs for my Android device?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/17152/16575). Your device not being detected: PC running Windows? If so, have you installed the drivers for your device?

Comment: When I plug in the unrooted device it is detected without a problem, when i plug in my rooted device I have an issue.  I have also browsed each one of the sites on the link provided with no luck of finding the rom I need.  I think my best bet would be just dipping my phone in water and sending it in.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this link that is what you want:[HTC](http://www.redmondpie.com/root-unroot-all-htc-android-devices-in-one-click-using-htc-quick-root-tool/)

Comment: Could you please include an excerpt of what's behind the link? Link-only answers are not considered helpful here, as when the link goes down they become useless.